# Test if Lua number is integer or float

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

In my C++ program, I need to know if a Lua variable is an integer number or a floating-point number. The C API provides `lua_isnumber()` but this function does not distinguish between `int/float/double`.

So far I have worked around this by using `modf()`:

```
if (lua_isnumber(luaCtx, -1)) // int / unsigned int / float:
{
    luaVarName = lua_tostring(luaCtx, -2);
    double n = static_cast<double>(lua_tonumber(luaCtx, -1));

    // Figure out if int or float:
    double fractPart, intPart;
    fractPart = modf(n, &intPart);

    if (fractPart != 0.0)
    {
        luaVarType = ScriptVar::TypeTag::Float;
        luaVarData.asFloat = static_cast<float>(n);
    }
    else
    {
        luaVarType = ScriptVar::TypeTag::Integer;
        luaVarData.asInteger = static_cast<int>(n);
    }
}
```

Does the Lua API provide a way to infer the variable type more precisely?

Comment: Nope. You can cast it to an unsigned type using `lua_tounsigned` or `lua_checkunsigned`. Otherwise you have to cast it like you have.

Comment: Lua 5.3 will have both integer and floating point types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
double n = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
if (n == (int)n) {
    // n is an int
} else {
    // n is a double
}
```

What this code does is just checking if n has any decimals or not.
If n is 1.5, then casting it to int ((int)n) will floor the value to 1, so:

1.5 == 1 is false, n is a double

But if n is lets say 4:

4 == 4 is true, n is a int

This works because to lua, the only numeric number that exist is double. So when converting a number from lua to C, we can choose to use int if the number is a integer(whole number).

Comment: This answer is up for deletion. Its hard to tell if this is a quality answer. Could you explain it a bit?

Comment: OK, so no extra info about numbers, you have to check it yourself. Easy enough with a type cast / `floor()`, etc.