# Lua - Detecting integers

Tags: c, lua

Lua behaves as follows :

```
print( 1 ) -- prints 1
print( 1.0 ) -- prints 1.0
```

Since Lua is using `lua_Number`, which is a floating point value (either float or double), for all number types (i.e both integers and reals), I guess it somehow keeps track of the actual nature of a number value, or else `print( 1 )` would print `1.0` since the information that that `1` is an integer would be lost when casting 1 to `lua_Number` at some point in the Lua's code.

Is there a way, using the C API of Lua 5.3.2, to detect whether a `lua_Number` was originally an integer or a real ?

Say I want to code a native function expecting either an integer or a real. How can I know, when poping my parameters, if the given value was `1` or `1.0` ?

Thanks.

PS : I already saw this answer : [Test if Lua number is integer or float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196042/test-if-lua-number-is-integer-or-float) but it doesn't solve my problem since checking if `number == (int) number` would indicate that any real like `N.0` would be an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua 5.3 uses `lua_Number` (default: `double`) to represent floating point numbers and `lua_Integer` (default: `long long`) for integers. Previous versions only had a floating-point type. The API has the function `lua_isinteger` to determine if a value is represented as an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also I see in lua.h that there is no type for integers, i.e not `LUA_INTEGER`, but only `LUA_TNUMBER` as before. So is the integer type a real Lua type that can be used for exemple to do : `type( 1 ) == "integer"` or is it some kind of hidden subtype ? Thanks.

Comment: @Virus721 Currently (as of Lua 5.4) `type(1)` returns `number`, so you'd have to use the C API to check using `lua_isinteger`

Comment: I think you could implement an `isinteger()` function in Lua using the C API? (I wonder why isinteger() isn't a core language function)